# How to prevent Angular from turning URL hash into a path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an angular app with a number of links. Clicking each link displays a particular set of data. I would like each link to set a hash in the URL, like http://foo.com/bar#item1, and I'd also like to show the page with the particular set of data displaying when that URL with the hash is accessed directly.

I was hoping to do it by reading / manipulating the $location.hash(), but as soon as I inject $location into my controller, the #item1 in the URL changes to #/item1. Is there a way to prevent Angular from doing this, and what's the best way of setting up what I described?

Comment: It's just guesswork, but maybe it could help to configure the locationProvider with `html5mode:true`: See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location - html5mode

Answer (score 0):

You could pass parameters in the routes `/bar/item1`, catch it with `$routeParams` and if exist make `$location.hash()`.

```
"controller"

var anchor = $routeParams.anchorBottom;
if(anchor){
  $location.hash(anchor);
  $anchorScroll();
}


"link to section"

$location.path('/heart/bottom');


"route"

.when('/heart/:anchorBottom',{
```

[You could see this running here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/gejWhtOZGLyrGYAMH9yp)